# Pandas to_sql without declaring schema in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I can successfully store my pandas dataframe into a MSSQL Server using df.to_sql.  However, I see many people specifying a schema using sqlalchemy something like this

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column


Base = declarative_base()

class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table'
    Thing = Column(Integer)
```

If I correctly format the column types with my dataframe, what benefit does a predefined SQLAlchemy table serve?

Comment: You may want to assign a column as an integer or some other type when pandas has the dtype as something else. `Specify the dtype (especially useful for integers with missing values). Notice that while pandas is forced to store the data as floating point, the database supports nullable integers.`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#sql-data-types